# How many cells does the hermaphrodite version of Caenorhabditis elegans have?

Tags: zoology, animal-models

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caenorhabditis_elegans) states:

> The male C. elegans, for example, has 1031 cells

How many cells does the female version have?

Comment: **Homework questions** and **trivial questions about basic biological concepts** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). https://www.google.com/#q=how+many+cells+in+female+c+elegans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

959 Somatic Cells according to [WormBase](http://www.wormbase.org) and The WormBook.